# i want to write unit test case for my angular js app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, unit-testing

I have a weather app that uses https://metaweather.com/api/ to fetch the weather the js code is as

```
angular.module('ourAppApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,apiFac) {

    $scope.displayCity = false;
    $scope.displayWeather = false;
    $scope.today = new Date();
    $scope.searchCity = function(){

        if($scope.cityInput != ""){ 
          apiFac.searchCity($scope.cityInput).then(function(response){
            $scope.searchResponse = response;
            $scope.displayCity = true;
          })
        }   
    }

    $scope.getcitydetails = function(item){
      $scope.cityInput = "";
      $scope.displayCity = false;
      $scope.selectedCity = item;

      apiFac.weatherReport(item.woeid).then(function(response){
        $scope.weatherResponse = response;
        $scope.displayCity = false;
        $scope.displayWeather = true;
      })
    }


})
```

and the index.html is as

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  <title>Weather app</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="ourAppApp">
  <div ng-view="">
  </div>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/factory/apiFac.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to write the unit test case for the angularjs functions, I am new to unit testing any help would be really appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Consider editing your question to make your problem __clearer__. In the meantime, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use cucumberjs. It uses a simple gherkin syntax and user friendly.
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js
If the problem in your mind is about the API call... then remember there are two things to test when it comes to javascript.

1. test the typescript viewmodels - this can be done by cucumberjs
2. test the UI - this can be done with help of Selenenium with chromedriver support. If you are using C# in the backend, then use specflow for unit testing. Or maybe even direct selenium.